# Is nlogn same as n^2logn^2

Tags: algorithm, big-o

When we calculate Big O, is *n*log*n* the same as *n*^2log*n*^2 ?(basically when *n* is replaced with *n* square)

I was discussing this today with a colleague who mentioned the *n*log*n* complexity of an algorithm is same when *n* becomes *n*^2.

That does not sound correct. Looking for expert opinions.

Comment: Forget the ```logN``` factor. How could ```N``` and ```N^2``` grow at the same rate for ```O(N)``` and ```O(N^2)``` to be equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true. You can look at the ratio of two functions and evaluate asymptotic limit

```
n^2*log(n^2) = 2*n^2*log(n)  (note that log(n^2) has the same oder as log(n))
ratio = [n*log(n)] / [2*n^2*log(n)] = 1/(2*n)
```

When n becomes larger, ratio tends to zero, so `n*log(n)` has lower order than  `n^2*log(n^2)`

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is probably thinking of the fact that O(log  n²) = O(log n). This means that O(n log  n²) = O(n log n) and O(n² log  n²) = O(n² log n); but it does *not* mean that O(n² log  n²) = O(n log n).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's clearly not correct.

Probably what your friend is confused by is that exponents inside a logarithm can be turned into multipliers: log *n*² = 2 log *n*. This means that *O*(log *n*²) = *O*(2 log *n*), and since multiplicative constants are dropped inside Big-O, *O*(2 log *n*) = *O*(log *n*).

As a rule of thumb, in Big-O analysis exponents inside logarithms can be discarded. This doesn't apply to regular non-logarithmic squaring, though.

- *O*(log *n*²) = *O*(log *n*)
- *O*(*n*²) ≠ *O*(*n*)
- *O*(*n*² log *n*) ≠ *O*(*n* log *n*)
- *O*(*n*² log *n*²) = *O*(n² log *n*) ≠ *O*(*n* log *n*)

Answer (score 0):

we can take the below order for big - oh

1<log n<root n<n<n log n<n^2<n^3<......2^n<3^n<....<n^n.

from this n^2 is one of the upper bound of n. So Big oh of n and n2 can't be the same.